# Erro com switch em swift

Tags: ios, swift, switch

Galera, estou tendo um erro no seguinte código. O erro esta no switch, aparece o seguinte erro:

> expected declaration.

O Que fazer?

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerAnalseOP1: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    var indice: Int?
    var string1 = "Primeira String"
    var string2 = "Segunda String"

    @IBOutlet weak var descricao: UITextView!

    switch indice {
        case 0:
            descricao.text = string1
        case 1:
            descricao.text = string2
        default:
            descricao.text = "Not Found"
    }

    func textViewShouldBeginEditing(descricao: UITextView) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        descricao.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Vlw pela ediçao, n vi que estava escrito tao errado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro de sintaxe aparece pois o switch está declarado no corpo da classe. O switch deve ser declarado dentro de algum método, ex:

```
class ViewControllerAnalseOP1: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    var indice: Int = 0
    var string1 = "Primeira String"
    var string2 = "Segunda String"

    @IBOutlet weak var descricao: UITextView!

    func textViewShouldBeginEditing(descricao: UITextView) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        descricao.delegate = self

        switch indice {
            case 0:
                descricao.text = string1
            case 1:
                descricao.text = string2
            default:
                descricao.text = "Not Found"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado deu certo